# WPF RichTextBox get selected element

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, richtextbox

I am adding hyperlink to a RichTextEditor ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3486064/713847)). But now I want to get the Hyperlink back when user selects the hyperlink. And here I meant I want the Hyperlink element not just the text.

What I'm trying to do is to create a pop-up like google docs for hyperlink. I can add the hyperlink just fine. But now I need to modify the existing link. Getting the display text is easy but to get the address of the link is tricky. And I don't want the whole paragraph and then look for the link because there can be multiple links in one paragraph.

I tried `richtextbox.Selection.Start.GetAdjacentElement(Forward/Backward)` but it's not always returning the hyperlink. Is there any way to get just the selected element/hyperlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I end up doing to get the hyperlink.

```
Hyperlink GetHyperlinkAtSelection()
{
  var selectedPointer = rtb.Selection.GetNextInsertionPosition(forward)

  if(sp == null)
    return;

  var para = sp.Paragraph;

  var hyperlink = para.Inlines.FirstOrDefault(x => 
    x.ContentStart.CompareTo(sp) == -1 && x.ContentEnd.CompareTo(sp) == 1);

  return hyperlink as Hyperlink;
}
```

to get hyperlink at caret position just change the first line of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, some helps are here ^^

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prajakta/archive/2006/10/17/autp-detecting-hyperlinks-in-richtextbox-part-i.aspx

Based on reference, I try to find NavigateUri

```
   public static Hyperlink GetHyberLink(this TextPointer pointer)
     {
         if (pointer == null)
         {
             return null;
         }     

         Inline parent = pointer.Parent as Inline;
         while (parent != null && !(parent is Hyperlink))
         {
             parent = parent.Parent as Inline;
         }

         return parent == null ? null : (Hyperlink)parent;
     }
```

Using:

```
Hyperlink hyperlink = RichTextBox.Selection.Start.GetHyberLink();
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(hyperlink.ElementStart, hyperlink.ElementEnd);
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
```

Result:
    The NavigateUri will be marked as red.

Comment: seen that before doesn't help me much to get the NavigateUri from the selected link